# How to add razor variables to column template in kendo grid for if else logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I am trying to use a kendo grid with Razor syntax, and using a if:else logic to build a header template. The problem I am having is that the if statement does not check a property of the model for the kendo grid, but a SessionHelper property from c# razor. I can't seem to get it correctly. I am currently using the following, but it is not working.

We are using ClientTemplate like so:

```
.ClientTemplate("#= getLinks(data)#")
```

The function code is listed below:

```
function getLinks(data) {

        var level2Access = '@SessionHelper.IsUserLevel2Access()';
        var model = "<a href='javascript:GetCertsHistory(" + data.ControlNumber + ")'>Certs</a> | " +
          "<a href='javascript:GetInvoicesHistory(" + data.ControlNumber + ")'>Invoices</a> | ";

        if (level2Access) {
            model += "<a href='javascript:GetItemToEdit(" + data.ControlNumber + ")'>Edit</a>";
        }

        return model;

    }
```

Now, what is strange is that if one object has the control number of all numeric, it works fine. If the control number is numeric then alpha it fails trying to just call the function for viewing certs.

The error is gets in the developer tools is here:

```
GetCertHistory(1210000bbbtest123)   "Invalid or unexpected token"
```

I have no idea on this one as to why this occurs only when the parameter is alphanumeric and not just numeric. I even thought maybe there was a special character I was not seeing, so I ran trim against the params, but it still occurs. Any thought's on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the way you are doing this to an external template something like this:

```
.ClientTemplate("#=getLinks(data)#")
```

then have a javascript function that gets the links for you like this (Untested but should work) :

```
 function getLinks(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var level2Access = '@SessionHelper.IsUserLevel2Access()';
        var model = "<a href='javascript:GetCertsHistory(\"" + data.ControlNumber +"\")'>Certs</a> | " +
          "<a href='javascript:GetInvoicesHistory(\"" + data.ControlNumber + "\")'>Invoices</a> | ";

        if (level2Access) {
            model += "<a href='javascript:GetItemToEdit(\"" + data.ControlNumber + "\")'>Edit</a>";
        }

        return model;

    }
```

alternatively you could look to use external templates for these links which may be a more maintainable solution in the future but this should work for you.

Any issues let me know and I will update the answer for you

Comment: Oh yea, that is a good idea. I don't know why I overlooked taking this route. lol Thanks!

Comment: I had to modify your code a little. I updated it in my question, but I am now getting invalid token error when trying to call the the proper model values in the function params when debugging in developer tools.

Comment: At least you got it working. Just let me know the edits you made and I will update my answer

Comment: Im still having one issue. When  a data.ControlNumber contains alphanumeric, it gives me invalid token error when trying to call the function. If it is only numeric or only alpha, then it works. Strange, but your idea opened it up for me to get closer to the solution.

Comment: I have added encapsulating quotes around the value so it should now work for you.